# Node.js Express Jade: Is there a way to define a JSON view for all URLs that (say) end with ".json"?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Most of my handlers look as follows:

```
function(req, res) {
  var data = ...;
  res.render('my_view', data);
}
```

I know that If I want to return JSON I need to change `res.render` to `res.json`, as follows:

```
function(req, res) {
  var data = ...;
  res.json(data);
}
```

when debugging I often want to see the raw data (in JSON format that was computed by the handler). To do that, I (manually) go to the handler callback and change `res.render('...',` to `res.json(`.

I am wondering whether there is a way to tell express that if the URL meets a certain condition token (say, ends with `.json`, or, alternatively, has a `?format=json` query param) then `res.view` will seamlessly delegate to `res.json` ?

Comment: how about this http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.format ?

Comment: Thanks, @vinayr. Unless I am missing something res.format() requires me to special-case 'application/json' in every handler I write. I am looking for a global solution.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just for debugging purpose then you could make a middleware that would override `render` method to `json`.
I will **not** recommend to use this in production.

In your `app.configure` add this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.json !== undefined) {
    res.render = function(name, data) {
      res.json(data);
    }
  }
  return next();
});
```

So what it does: if request has `json` in query, then it will override `render` method and will call `json` instead.

So test it with: http://example.com/test?json

Comment: just curious (and for clarification sake), why would you not recommend to use this in production?

Comment: It is not good practice to override methods from other APIs as it can lead to some misbehaviours. There is no much performance difference with this, but I would just have condition in middleware where you call render, so that you as developer decide where it should apply and wheres not, or at least have it as middleware, and not for all requests, and add before your controller middleware so it replaces only on those routes you really need it.